# Does strictly positive density function on the real line with infinite expected value exist?

Tags: probability-distributions

The problem is as stated in the title. I am looking for an example or a disproof, whether there exists a continuous density function on the whole real line with infinite expected value.

Once again:

The density function $f$ must be

$1.$ Positive on $\mathbb{R}$

$2.$ Continuous on  $\mathbb{R}$

$3.$ $E[X]=\infty$ with $X\sim f$

Comment: Would something like a Cauchy density on $\mathbb R^+$ and a zero-mean normal density on $\mathbb R^-$ work? The variance of the normal density can be adjusted to make both functions have the same value at $0$ and both densities have slope $0$ at $0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I don't mind. It can be constructed as how we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, consider the density
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}, & x > 0,\\
\displaystyle \frac{1}{\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{\pi}\right),&x < 0,\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{\pi}, & x = 0\end{cases}$$
which can be recognized as a standard Cauchy density on $\mathbb R^+$ and a
zero-mean normal density with variance $\frac{\pi}{2}$ on $\mathbb R^-$.
Note that $f(x)$ is positive and continuous on $\mathbb R$ as desired,
and more strongly, it also differentiable on $\mathbb R$ (at $x=0$,
both the left derivative and the right derivative have value $0$).
If $f(x)$ is not required to be differentiable everywhere (that is,
continuity is sufficient), we could, for example, set $f(x)$ to 
$\frac 1\pi\exp(2x/\pi)$
for $x<0$ instead of the normal density.

Thus,
$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty xf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is unbounded while 
$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^0 xf(x)\,\mathrm dx =- \frac 12$,
and so $\displaystyle\int_\infty^\infty xf(x)\,\mathrm dx = E[X] = \infty$.

Comment: I think it is not differentiable at $0$. I started to wonder if the condition "continuous" would be differentiable?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: Both functions are symmetric about $x=0$, so they both have zero derivative there.

Comment: @TonyK I just used mathematica and got the result "indeterminate" for point $0$. Used simply the piecewise function.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: Well, Mathematica is just confused then. The function is clearly differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Thanks for fixing the typo in the Cauchy density. The $f(x)$ I specified is continuous at $0$ and is also differentiable at $0$ since, as TonyK points out, both the Cauchy and the normal density have derivative $0$ at $0$. (I had said so in my comment but hadn't included it above; I will fix my answer when I have some time).

Comment: @DilipSarwate that is okay. everything is clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Dilip: In your last sentence, I think both instances of $\int f(x)dx$ should be $\int xf(x)dx$.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks, I am fixing the whole answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. This is not quite right, because

- it's symmetric, so we don't get $E[X]=+\infty$;
- $\int_{\mathbb R}f \ne 1$.

But $\int_0^\infty xf(x)\mathrm{dx} = +\infty$, so you can modify it to meet your requirements:

1. for negative arguments, change it to a function that tends to $0$ fast enough as $x \to -\infty$, e.g. $f(x)=e^x$ for $x < 0$;
2. multiply it by a suitable constant so that $\int_{\mathbb R}f = 1$.

Comment: I had another example: with the same spirit and I ended up with a mean $0$ eventually. Therefore, I am looking for an explicit answer. Density $f(x)...$.

Comment: btw thank you for the answer.